# mySQL server in XAMP don't start

Tags: mysql

I read all of articles about my problem but it still not working

How can I solve this issue?

Here is my log file:

```
2015-11-10 15:26:56 10fc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-10 15:26:56 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1835027
2015-11-10 15:26:57 6140 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2015-11-10 15:26:57 4348 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.1.8-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Normal shutdown

2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5732 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2015-11-10 15:27:11 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1835037
2015-11-10 15:27:13 5152 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete

2016-06-02 14:23:12 c10 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835037
2016-06-02 14:23:12 6804 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:23:12 3088 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:48:22 10a0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4524 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:48:22 4256 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:48:26 1930 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:48:26 5968 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:48:26 6448 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:48:29 16cc InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:48:29 8112 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:48:29 5836 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:49:50 1d18 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:49:50 7448 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:49:51 7448 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:49:51 7448 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:49:51 7448 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:49:51 3128 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:49:51 7448 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:49:51 7448 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:49:51 7448 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:49:51 7448 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:49:51 7448 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:49:58 5e8 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:49:58 4724 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:49:58 1512 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:50:01 14f0 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:50:01 1264 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:50:01 5360 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:53:10 1340 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:53:10 5072 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:53:10 4928 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:58:04 147c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:58:04 147c InnoDB: Warning: Setting innodb_use_sys_malloc to FALSE is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:58:04 5244 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:58:05 5244 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:58:05 5244 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:58:05 5244 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:58:05 332 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:58:05 5244 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:58:05 5244 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:58:05 5244 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:58:05 5244 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:58:05 5244 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:59:17 126c InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:59:17 126c InnoDB: Warning: Setting innodb_use_sys_malloc to FALSE is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4652 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:59:17 4716 [ERROR] Aborting

2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Warning] option 'innodb-purge-threads': unsigned value 0 adjusted to 1
2016-06-02 14:59:30 1334 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:59:30 1334 InnoDB: Warning: Setting innodb_use_sys_malloc to FALSE is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: Using generic crc32 instructions
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.28-76.1 started; log sequence number 1835047
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] InnoDB: !!! innodb_force_recovery is set to 3 !!!
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4404 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port. Got error: 10048: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.


2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
2016-06-02 14:59:30 4916 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Thanks.

Comment: Change the port and try again?

Comment: @SilentMonk is right, it seems like that port is taken by some other process and the mysqld cant use.

Comment: it is used by another mysql instance that was not properly closed. I assume that you are on windows, I think you can kill previous mysql processes or restart the computer.

Comment: On Linux it seems the culprit of this, was MariaDB was utilizing said port. The following command let me see which programs were occupying the port: sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN

Answer (score 26):

I ran into this same issue when I had MySQL Workbench and XAMPP downloaded.
Since they're both trying to access Port 3306 an error occurs. I'm running this on Windows 10, I'm not sure if this fix also works on Mac & Linux.
I changed the port of XAMPP to 3307 and left the MySQL untouched. Here's how I did that:
*Take into consideration that the line numbers may be different on your system.

1. In the XAMPP GUI click on "Config" -> "Service and Port Settings" -> "MySQL" tab -> Change Main Port to 3307 -> Save -> Save
2. Locate the installation file for XAMPP -> open MySQL folder -> open bin folder -> right click on "my.ini" and edit it
3. Change the following lines:
   (Line 20) Port = 3306 -> Port = 3307
   (Line 28) Port = 3306 -> Port = 3307

Save the file, restart your computer, and the server should run.

Comment: As mentioned in other answers, changing the port number is not ideal since 3306 is the standard port for exactly this use case.

Comment: Thank you very much Ryan, on my end I use wnmp, based from your solution, I turned off mysql service on xampp.

Comment: I don't know. Changing your MySQL port because MySQL doesn't start is like telling someone that if their car doesn't start, use another car. It deflects from the actual problem car #1 is having.

Comment: @Ryan Russell , this worked well, however, on top of the steps given by Ryan, you also need to change the **mysqli.default_port** in  php.ini otherwise phpmyadmin will not start well.

**Steps to change php.ini** 
1. In the XAMPP control panel, under Apache click config
2. Select  PHP(php.ini)
3. Change the port in mysqli.default_port from 3306 to 3307

Comment: @TARKUS My answer is a mitigation, not a solution. If you are trying to run this in a production system you should definitely get the port situation figured out or else it may run into more issues.

Answer (score 18):

I just ran into this problem myself after I installed XAMPP for Apache. I decided to use it for a localhost of MySQL too. Here's what I did to get it to work.

In windows, open command prompt, type:
`netstat -ano|find "3306"`

The PID LISTENING was `4608`.
Opened Task Manager, went to Details tab.
Found the PID, it was a mysql.exe from another application.
Right click the application and select End Task.

Restart XAMPP.

I don't recommend changing the Port Number just because `3306` is a Standard assigned port to MySQL as well as `33060`, `33061`, and `33062`. In a few cases, I have seen Port `22` assigned. There is a protocol set up for this and when to use which one.

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered this error. Since I have XAMPP and MySQL Workbench, I had a feeling that the issue was MySQL related thus I opened the Task Manager using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> and selecting Task Manager.

Then on the services tab, I searched for any running MySQL programs, left-clicked it, and stopped it.

Then started MySQL on the XAMPP control panel.

I think you can try this first then proceed to other options in case it doesn't work.

Comment: ctrl + alt + del

Comment: Upvoted, not because it is the definitive answer, but because it's the right first thing to try.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same case because in someway i installed MariaDB and it used the port of 3306, so what i did is to go to the Task-manager > Services and did a sort to find the port using "3306" in PID column then i stop that service. after i started MySQL in the xampp control panel and it worked very well.

My conclusion is that you should use command option (1):

1. *netstat -ano|find "3306"*
2. find that port in Task-manager > Services
3. stop the application using that port in PID
4. Click to start MySQL again.

Answer (score 2):

Windows 10 Microsoft Windows [version 10.0.19041.450]
Laragon 4.0.16 190914 (MySQL 5.7.24_winx64) on 3306
Xampp 3.2.4 (10.4.13-MariaDB) on 3306

Some log error lines of MySQL 5.7.24_winx64 on 3306 on Laragon 4.0.16 190914 :

- '::' resolves to '::';
  Server socket created on IP: '::'.
  Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: No such file or directory

No way to fix this (sfc /scannow, change port to 3307=nok) so I decided to remove HyperV/Sandbox and all Windows 10 options related to HyperV (lan adapters issues ?).

After the removals of the HyperV Windows 10 options + reboot, Laragon MySQL and Xampp MariaDB are working like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try this command :

-> netstat -ano|find "3306"

```
and go to Task manager -> services or Task manager -> details check your running 
PID on port 3306 and end that task.

restart your MySQL it's work!!
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. even changing ports does not make it run.
finally I found these commands and it solved.

run command prompt as administrator

type
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

restart your windows

try to run your xampp mysql, again, it shoud be run

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Daniel and @Elzo

Try to run this below command in cmd prompt

`netstat -ano|find "3306"`

Eg:

> TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       5164
>
> TCP    [::]:3306              [::]:0                 LISTENING       5164

It will let you know whether any process is utilizing port 3306 or not.

If you are using xampp older version of xampp had portcheck.ext file you could even use that.

If its mysql than stop and then try to start mysql again.
You could even use the pid number(Here 5164) and check in windows task manager who is utilizing these pid so that you would come to know the exact process name

Answer (score 0):

I simply deleted MySql Workbench and it no longer gives me this error.