# How can I make MySQL server in XAMPP work well after a crash?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, xampp, windows-10

The MySQL server in XAMPP does not start well anymore.

I tried changing the port as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37589791/258462), and the server still does not start, although it attempts to do this: a new PID is shown for a fraction of second next to MySQL in the context of the screenshot below when clicking on `Start`.

I also tried to run `netstat -ano|find "3306"` (I tried with 3307 too) but it does not show anything, the same when running it in the Command Prompt as admin. I also restarted the computer and removed the new PHP code I wrote today. Yesterday everything worked fine.

Note: the day before yesterday I had my working computer instantly turned off by mistake.

A screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

The log file is [here](https://gist.github.com/silviubogan/e3d039ecbda3ab9c3f971af0746f6816) and a part of it says that it is a bug, but a bug of MariaDB which I do not use.

I am a beginner, and I use MySQL just for WordPress.

Running `netstat -ab` results in [this](https://gist.github.com/silviubogan/8cc82c43f55051a4f798eac98eaa6d23).

Now I am checking if there are updates to XAMPP.

It seems that there are no updates to XAMPP.

Comment: Read errors in red colors! or update xampp

Comment: the error log suggests another process running on port 3306 ~ try running `netstat -ab` from commandline to see if there is already something on that port

Comment: You might find this link useful https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=72437

Comment: @RamRaider I posted the output of `netstat -ab` at the end of the question. It does not show `3306`.

Comment: @jeff Related to this question, your link is currently not useful for me. I made the change and the same red text shows up. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all check your port and check if your firewall is not blocking that port, try different ports 3306, 3307, 3308.

This is your error:

```
2020-02-20  9:40:14 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-02-20  9:40:14 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-02-20  9:40:14 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I would re-install xampp instead of spending tons of time on trying to find error.

There are some explanition here : https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,652134,652135#msg-652135

Open shell from from control panel and start mysql with this command:

```
mysqld –-console –-skip-grant-tables –-skip-external-locking
```

Open another shell from control panel and repair database with this command:

```
mysqlcheck -r --databases mysql --use-frm
```

Stop mysql, close shells and restart mysql normally.

Also see **InnoDB Corruption and Recovery** https://chepri.com/mysql-innodb-corruption-and-recovery/

Comment: The source of the source (the source used in th 2019 Stack Overflow answer) is revealed, but it is plagiarised without any clear indication it has been ***wholesale copied*** from [the 2019 Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56847804/xampp-mysql-service-crash-after-reboot/57001732#57001732).