# MySQL does not start in xampp (PHP 7)

Tags: mysql, xampp

MySQL has stopped working for me, without any changes on my settings. I use xampp version 7.14, because the server isn't migrated to PHP 8. (It worked without problems until a few days ago)
I also have a version 8.x on my computer and that works with the same port, so the problem is not a blocked Port. (I never run both at the same time). A change of the port doesn't help either.

The log file:

```
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xamppV7\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xamppV7\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-09-05 16:16:36 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-09-05 16:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.24 started; log sequence number 10724445; transaction id 8180
2022-09-05 16:16:37 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xamppV7\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-09-05 16:16:37 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-09-05 16:16:37 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

There are no errors, has someone an idea?

Comment: It looks like you may have a port conflict. Try changing your MySQL port and see if it runs. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37589791/mysql-server-in-xamp-dont-start) helps.

Comment: @GRIV As mentioned, it works with another XAMPP version, which use the same port. It also doesn't help to change the port.

Comment: Gotcha, dumb question but are you fully sure your other XAMPP version is not running at the same time? taking your port.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure - I added this information just now ;)

Comment: I'd need a lot more information to help you out with this unfortunately, I did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47691238/mysql-wont-run-when-i-am-using-xampp-server) around corrupted files, however.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling helped me. Thanks for your help and time ;)

Comment: No problem. Uninstalling / Reinstalling is always a good time. Glad you got it to work.